# Custom field in ActiveModel Serializer with another serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have `User` model with `has_many :sessions`. But for one particular request I want to send only one session based on request device platform (iOS, Android).

The problem is that I have separate `UserSerializer` and `UserSessionSerializer` and I want to pass `UserSessionSerializer` as option in `UserSerializer` for `:session` field. Like this:

```
# UsersController
render json: @user, serializer: UserSerializer, session: @session # @user's session founded by platform

# UserSerializer
attributes :id, :email, :username, :session

def session
  @instance_options[:session], serializer: UserSessionSerializer
end
```

It is impossible, because I can pass serializer only in `has_one` and `has_many` as I understand. But I don't want to render all user sessions in JSON with `has_many`, only founded one.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good just use `UserSessionSerializer.new` instead of  `serializer: UserSessionSerializer`

```
render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(@user, session: @session) }

attributes :id, :email, :username, :session

def session
  UserSessionSerializer.new(self.instance_options[:session]) if self.instance_options[:session].present?
end
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! I knew it might be possible ;)